# check in js if actual text or whitespace of an element was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to differ between the text and the white space of an element if clicked.

[image: Example:]

I have unsuccessful tried following:

```
body.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default context menu
    const clickX = e.clientX;
    const clickY = e.clientY;
    item = e.target; // Get the clicked element
    if (item.textContent.trim() !== '') { do sth...; }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default context menu
    const clickX = e.clientX;
    const clickY = e.clientY;
    const item = e.target;
    if (item.tagName === 'SPAN') {
      console.log('text clicked')
    } else if (item.tagName === 'P') {
      console.log('paragraph clicked')
    }
});
```

```css
p {
  background: red;
}

span {
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Text</span></p>
```